# Rails 3: Text_field_tag default value if params[:something].blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters

How would one do something like:

```
  = f.input_field :age,
                  :collection => 18..60,
                  :id => 'age',
                  :selected => params[:age].blank? or "20"
```

Above doesen't work. I want to be able to set a default value if there is *no param* available for that attribute.

Any smart way to do this thx!

EDIT 1:
Full form:

```
  = simple_form_for  :people,  :url => request.fullpath, :method => :get,  :html => { :class => 'form-search' } do |f|
    #container_search_small.form-search


      = f.input_field :age,
                      :collection => 18..60,
                      :id => 'age',
                      :selected => params[:people][:age_from] || "20"



      = f.submit "Go »"
```

Comment: try params[:age] || "20"

Comment: I think javascript should be used to set the default value

Comment: It should be possible to set  the value with the :selected based on the params BUT if the params are not submitted this fails. Im getting a undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using helpers that are taking their values from the object you're building the form on.

So in your controller, you should preset the values on the object.

```
def some_action
  @people = People.new
  @people.age = params[:age] || 20
end
```

Then in the form, remove the `:selected` option and it should be fine. Make sure you build the form for `@people` :

```
= simple_form_for  @people,  :url => request.fullpath, :method => :get,  :html => { :class => 'form-search' } do |f|
  #container_search_small.form-search


    = f.input_field :age,
                  :collection => 18..60,
                  :id => 'age'



    = f.submit "Go »"
```

Comment: Anthony I update my post with full example. This is part of a search form, im not creating just want to be able to set the values back.

Comment: Edited my answer. The way you're building your form with `simple_form_for`, you can set values on a fake instance of @people and it should work. If you don't want to do it this way, you could always create a `form_tag` instead : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: Ok I see this is basically almost the solution, but in this case the url request.fullpath would require to initialize a complete people in every action or I should use a before filter somehow. I try your solution. say you want age_from and age_to you add those to attributes accessible? like "Virtual columns"

Comment: If you want to add search options that have nothing to do with fields in the db, then you should consider building a form with form_tag instead, so you don't end up creating virtual attributes for search options. It doesn't make much sense to have `age_from` and `age_to` on a People model.

Comment: form_tag seems not the way.. no access to model data wich is a must have, I have big collections I don't want to replicate by manually coding them in the form ;s

Comment: No but with form tag you can set default values for each field. Just output your model data manually !

Comment: Ill try this It seems the form_for cannot use params at all correctly